# How can I check if an optional implemented method is not defined more elegantly?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have an Angular based Web Application based on Typescript, where I have an Interface, which has some methods like this:

```
export interface ComponentBase {
  componentInit(data: any): void;
  componentPause?(data: any): void;
  componentDeInit?(data: any): void;
}
```

Now, because the Pause method as an Example is optional, when I want to check if it is defined, I am doing something like this:

```
    if (currentComponent.customComponent.componentPause)
       currentComponent.customComponent.componentPause!(null);
```

But WebStorm underlines the second line yellow and now I'm thinking, that I'm doing it wrong. Is there a way, to make this more elegant? (It is working by the way, but it is annoying this way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining with function calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_function_calls), a lesser known feature:

```js
currentComponent.customComponent.componentPause?.(null);
```

If `currentComponent.customComponent.componentPause` is `null` or `undefined`, the interpreter will not try to call it.